# Functional Equations Using Calculus

Tags: calculus

Find all functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$ we have $$|f(x+y)-f(x-y)-y| \leq y^2$$
I saw a solution to this problem as follows:
$$$$Dividing by $|2y|$ on both the sides of the equation we get $$|\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}-\frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{|y|}{2}$$ Now by putting $x-y=a$ and $2y=b$ we get $$0 \leq |\frac{f(b+a)-f(a)}{b}-\frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{|b|}{4}$$ Now taking the limits as ${b \to 0}$ we get $f'(a)=\frac{1}{2}$ for every $a \in \Bbb R$ so we get $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+c$
$$$$But while substituting $x-y=a$ and $2y=b$ we see that $a$ is dependent on $b$ as $x$ and $y$ are independent from each other.So the limit $$\lim_{b \to 0}|\frac{f(b+a)-f(a)}{b}|$$ is not the derivative of the function at the point $a$

Can anyone please explain me all this?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Which part is unclear?

Comment: I am asking that is the solution correct or my reasoning is correct??

Comment: a and b are independent , because give any value to values to a and b, then it becomes 2 equation and 2 variables, giving x and y.

Comment: It is true that if you fix $a$ and vary $b$ (giving it successively smaller values) you use different values of **both** $x$ **and** $y$ in the given inequality. But for any $a,b$ you can find appropriate $x,y$ and so the reasoning given in the proof you quote is correct.

Comment: @aryanbansal but how $y$ depends on $b$ and $a$ depends on $y$ so how $a$ and $b$ are independent

Comment: You can take $x=y+x_1$ then $a$ doesn't depend on $y$.

Comment: I am just saying you can put any value of a and b , they dont depend on each other (a and b), so they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the inequality

$$
0 \leq \left|\frac{f(x+y) - f(x-y)}{2y} - \frac{1}{2}\right| \leq \frac{|y|}{2},
$$

let us make some algebra here:

$$
0 \leq \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{f(x+y) - f(x)}{y} + \frac{f(x-y)-f(x)}{-y} - 1\right| \leq \frac{|y|}{2}.
$$

Now, taking limits as $y\rightarrow 0$, we obtain

$$
|f'(x) + f'(x) - 1| = 0 \Leftrightarrow f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.  
$$

$f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + C$.

So, your answer is correct.

Comment: But it is not given that $f'(x)$ exists